# Makefile without specifying the source file

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a makefile as follows:

```
# Makefile for VocabLearn

MACHTYPE=$(shell uname -m)

GCC         = g++

CC=gcc
# OPTFLAGS=-g2
OPTFLAGS=-O3 -ffast-math -Wall -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -funroll-loops -march=core2
OTHERFLAGS=-Wall -fopenmp

INCLUDE_PATH=-I../lib/ann_1.1/include/ANN -I../lib/ann_1.1_char/include/ANN \
    -I../lib/imagelib -I../VocabLib -I../lib/zlib/include
LIB_PATH=-L../lib -L../VocabLib -L../lib/zlib/lib

OBJS=VocabLearn.o

LIBS=-lvocab -lANN -lANN_char -limage -lz

CPPFLAGS=$(INCLUDE_PATH) $(LIB_PATH) $(OTHERFLAGS) $(OPTFLAGS)

BIN=VocabLearn

all: $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJS)
    g++ -o $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(BIN) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ $(LIB)
```

When I 'make' it in the prompt, it works fine and output the following info:(I use Mac OS, c++ means clang compiler)

> c++  -I../lib/ann_1.1/include/ANN -I../lib/ann_1.1_char/include/ANN
>   -I../lib/imagelib -I../VocabLib -I../lib/zlib/include -L../lib -L../VocabLib -L../lib/zlib/lib -Wall -fopenmp -O3 -ffast-math -Wall -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -funroll-loops -march=core2  -c -o VocabLearn.o VocabLearn.cpp
>
> g++ -o -I../lib/ann_1.1/include/ANN -I../lib/ann_1.1_char/include/ANN
>   -I../lib/imagelib -I../VocabLib -I../lib/zlib/include -L../lib -L../VocabLib -L../lib/zlib/lib -Wall -fopenmp -O3 -ffast-math -Wall -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -funroll-loops -march=core2 -o VocabLearn VocabLearn.o -lvocab -lANN -lANN_char -limage -lz

I just want to know how this makefile works. As you can see, since this makefile doesn't specify which source code to compile, how does the compiler know it is 'VocabLearn.cpp' that it should process? (My guess is that it will search source file according to the name of the object file, VocabLearn.o) Also this line seems a bit strange for me:

```
g++ -o $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(BIN) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
```

Why is there a '-o' before '$(CPPFLAGS)'?

Comment: That line is strange... and quite likely wrong. That `-o` is likely swallowing the first argument in `$(CPPFLAGS)` unless `g++` argument parsing is very clever.

Comment: @EtanReisner: It is indeed wrong; but harmless since it just swallows the first include directory, which isn't needed for linking.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: But it doesn't swallow the first directory, as you can see from the output.

Comment: @NothingMore: It's still in the command line; but as the argument of the first (erroneous) `-o`, so that it loses its meaning and doesn't specify an include directory. It's then overridden by the second `-o`.

Answer (score 7):

This makefile is using [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Implicit.html#Using-Implicit) to compile the source files. The rule:

```
$(BIN): $(OBJS)
```

asks for the object files in `OBJS`, and make already knows how to build `VocabLearn.o` if there is a file `VocabLean.cpp`.

Comment: So the implicit rules can also include the needed directories and link the needed .obj file, right?

Comment: @NothingMore: Yes, the implicit rule for compiling C++ will include `$(CPPFLAGS)` in the compiler flags.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is an implicit rule to convert *.cpp files to *.o files, however you have to have *.o as a dependency in one your targets. In the given Makefile, you have VocabLearn.o as a dependency for $(BIN). So, VocabLearn.o gets auto-generated from VocabLearn.cpp file.